# Location of robot

Tags: navigation, odometry, gmapping, robot, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the noob question but im kind of lost and confused.  When i have a robot, pioneer 3dx, and im using navigation and gmapping to make it navigate a environment, when i want to know where am i or my position and orientation how can i accomplish this? I am confused to which topic gives me this information, and also how can i obtain that information. I really appreciate some help thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107286/location-of-robot/) by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the robot is using a standard setup, the robot's location is defined to some/multiple frames. It's position in the map is usually given by the /map -> /base_link tf transform.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-12-12**:
@dornhege How can i subscribe to this topic??

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-12**:
Use a TFListener. Check out the tf tutorials for an example.